# Why find('a') skips main domain returning next paths?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

**example below:**

```
$site = file_get_html('stackoveflow'); // 
$site->find('a'); // returns /questions/ask?wizard=1 skipping main domain part
```

.
How can I get full src?

Comment: It's probably not there in the source. Most sites don't use FQDN for links that are relative to the current domain. You will have to generate the full URL by using the known host (which you used to get the content) and the link you get from the `find`.

Comment: Does it exist in the source?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no full domain. Thanx for everyone for your response.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: I solved that problem with concatenating and now I got full urls, but when I click  a link, it passes on with root path: php/https://stackoverflow... php/ - is a file where it's located. So how could I remove it and pass on to right link?